# How to get other column value if login successfull in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have one table called Users, which have 4 columns

- UserId
- UserName
- Password
- Role

**If login is successful, I want to know the UserId and Role values ,**

for login validate I wrote following function,

```
 private bool ValidationFunction(string username, string pwd)
    {
        bool boolReturnValue = false;

        string s = "correct connection string";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s);
        con.Open();
        string sqlUserName;
        sqlUserName = "SELECT UserName,Password FROM Users WHERE UserName ='" + username + "' AND Password ='" + pwd + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName, con);

        string CurrentName;
        CurrentName = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (CurrentName != null)
        {
            boolReturnValue = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Session["UserName"] = "";
            boolReturnValue = false;
        }
        return boolReturnValue;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of executeScalar you need ExecuteReader, the result of which will contain one row you'll need to Read(), which will contain the columns you selected. Really any of the samples on MSDN will do that.

Comment: On a side note, Never.... ever..... concatenate strings like that in a SQL QUERY. I could pass "blah' or 1 = 1;--" as my username and would authenticate successfully every time.

Answer (score 4):

`ExecuteScalar()` function returns only the `top record value of the first column`. So you need to use `ExecuteReader()` instead.

Other important thing is you better use a parameterised query to pass those user typed values into the database. You are open for sql injection attacks this way.

Try this:

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
{
    string sql= "select userId,role from users " +
                "where username=@uName and password=@pWord";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cnn))
    {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uName", username);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pWord", pwd);

         cnn.Open();
         SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

         while (reader.Read())
         {
            //get the reader values here.
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: For example, as the user name, "blah' or 1 = 1;--" would do the trick.

Comment: Also a good idea to store these passwords hashed and compare the hashed values when attempting login.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely: Absolutely, those are design issues. Also making sure username is unique is another one. Microsoft Membership System is a good one with role management support and hashed passwords + .net support.

Answer (score 1):

If `UserID` and `Role` are in the Users table, you can use the code below.  It has the added benefit of protection from SQL injection attacks using parameters.

```
private class User
{
    public int UserID {get;set;}
    public string Role {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}

}
private bool ValidationFunction(string username, string pwd, out User)
    {
        bool boolReturnValue = false;

        string s = "correct connection string";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s);
        con.Open();
        string sqlUserName;
        sqlUserName = "SELECT UserName,Password,UserID,Role FROM Users WHERE UserName =@usr AND Password=@pwd";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("usr", username));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pwd", pwd));

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            boolReturnValue = true;
            User = new User(){UserName = username, UserID=reader.GetInt32(2), Role=reader.GetString(3)};
        }
        else
        {
            Session["UserName"] = "";
            boolReturnValue = false;
        }
        return boolReturnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use query

```
SqlDataReaer reader= Select *from Users where password="yourPassword"
```

and then you can get whatever you want i.e. `reader["userName"]` etc